# What is a good general purpose GnuPG key setup?

Tags: key-management, pgp

Since most key types can be used for multiple purposes, namely certification, authentication, encryption and signatures, one could simply use one key for everything - which is a *bad* idea, as elaborated e.g. [by Thomas Pornin](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/8563/3272). So one should use different key pairs for different purposes, with different backup methods (decryption should remain possible "forever", while signature keys can "simply" be replaced) and securing. But I haven't managed to find a one-in-all write up of best practice summarizing answers to the following questions:

- What type of key should be used for which purpose (RSA, DSA, ... how many bits, when should they expire etc)?
- Should all keys be (separate?) subkeys of the certification master key or be individual master keys signed by the former one? I found some non-trivial guides on how to remove the secret master key from your day-to-day used subkeys, but is the trouble involved really worth having a shorter chain-of-trust to these keys compared to an entirely separate certification key?
- How important is it actually to keep the certification key offline when one uses a) a "really" strong passphrase or b) a hardware device like an OpenPGP card?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

## About Using Subkeys

Use one primary key for *each identity* you need, otherwise, use subkeys.

Examples for using multiple primary keys:

- You don't want to mix up your private and professional keys
- You need some key *not* connected with your "real life" identity, eg. when prosecuted by the authorities

Examples for using subkeys:

- You want to use multiple keys for multiple devices (so you won't have to revoke your computer's key if you lose your mobile)
- You want to switch keys regularly (eg., every some years) without losing your reputation in the Web of Trust

I recently posted about [How many OpenPGP keys to make](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/29858/19837) in another answer.

## About Key Sizes

The [**GnuPG developers recommend using 2k RSA keys**](http://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-announce/2009q3/000291.html) for both encryption and signing. This will be definitely fine for currently used subkeys.

As your primary key will *not be used for anything but keysigning and validating signatures* (and revocation of course), it is seen as good practice to have a quite huge key here, while using smaller sizes (huge enough for time you will need them) for subkeys (which will speed up calculations and reduce file sizes).

I had a [more detailed answer facing RSA with DSA/Elgamal](https://superuser.com/a/541162/102155) for another question at Superuser, go there for reading further.

## Key Expiration

There are two ways a private key could get compromised:

1. Somebody is able to steal it from you
2. Somebody is able to recalculate it from your public key

First is a matter of your computer's security (and how you use your key, read below), second is a matter of time. Today (and probably the next few years), RSA 2k keys will be totally fine. But computing power rises dramatically, so an attacker needs less CPU cores/graphic cards/computers/power plants to recalculate your private key. Also, glitches could be found in the used algorithms, leading to much less computing power needed. Quantum computers could speed up things even more.

A **key expiration date** will limit the validity of your key to a given time you expect it to be secure. Any attacker cracking it afterwards will only be able to read encrypted data send to you, but nobody will use it any more; if an attacker gets hold of your key and you stay unnoticed, at least it will stop him from having use from it after a given time.

**Expiring your primary key** will let you lose all your Web of Trust reputation, but at least invalidates your key after a given time if you lose access (what should never ever happen, read on at the end of my answer).

## Storing your Primary Key Offline

Your primary key is the most crucial one. All trust - both incoming and outgoing - is connected with this. If somebody gets access to it, he's able to:

- Create new keys using your name (and GnuPG always uses your newest subkey by default!)
- Revoking subkeys and primary keys
- Issuing trust to other keys, which is the worst thing to happen: An attacker could create a new key, giving it trust from your old one and then revoke your old key, leaving you without any access to your "moved" identity - he's literally **overtaking your identity**.

> How important is it actually to keep the certification key offline when one uses a) a "really" strong passphrase [...]?

Your computer always could be hacked or infected by some malware downloading your keys and installing a key logger to fetch your password (and this is not a matter of which operating system you use, all of them include severe security holes nobody knows about at this time).

**Keeping your primary (private) key offline is a good choice** preventing these problems. It includes some hassles, but reduces risks as stated above.

Highest security would of course mean to use a separate, offline computer (hardware, no virtual machine!) to do all the key management using your primary key and only transferring OpenPGP data (foreign keys and signatures you issued) using some thumb drive.

> b) a hardware device like an OpenPGP card?

OpenPGP smart cards are somewhere in between storing it offline on a thumbdrive, but attaching it to your computer for signing and using another offline computer dedicated to this purpose. Your private key will never leave the smart card (except for backup purpose) which requires an "admin PIN", all signing and even key creation will happen inside the card. "Using" your key (encryption, signing, giving trust) will only require a "user PIN", so even if you connect the card to a "harmed" computer, the attacker will not be able to completely overtake your ID.

You can store your public key wherever you want, for having real use of OpenPGP, you even should send it (and your other public keys) to the keyservers.

---

And do not forget to create and print a revocation certificate of your primary key. Losing your private key not having this certificate means there is a key you cannot access any more lingering on the keyservers and **you can't do anything about it**.

Print it, possibly several times, and put it to places you trust. Your parents, some bank deposit box, ... - if this certificate leaks, worst thing to happen is losing your Web of Trust.

Answer (score 21):

### Cookbook

This is a cookbook approach which exemplifies the nice answer above. It is a distilled version of [Generating More Secure GPG Keys: A Step-by-Step Guide](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2013/11/24/secure-gpg-keys-guide/) which separates all those functions into separate keys

#### Create primary key

```
$ gpg --expert --gen-key
```

> (8) RSA (set your own capabilities)

```
Your selection? 8
```

> (S) Toggle the sign capability

```
Your selection? s
```

> (E) Toggle the encrypt capability

```
Your selection? e
```

> (Q) Finished

```
Your selection? q

What keysize do you want? (2048) 4096
Key is valid for? (0) 3y
Is this correct? (y/N)y
```

next add UID, email and passphrase.

This generates a *certify-only primary key*.

#### Create signing (etc.) subkeys

```
$ gpg --expert --edit-key john.doe@example.com
gpg> addkey
```

> (8) RSA (set your own capabilities)

```
Your selection? 8
Your selection? e
Your selection? q

What keysize do you want? (2048) 3072
Key is valid for? (0) 6m
Is this correct? (y/N)y
Really create? (y/N) y
```

This generates a sign-only subkey.

> (Repeat this addkey process for the Encryption and Authentication subkeys)

[...]

> When we’re finished, we’ll save the key to our keyring.

```
gpg> save
```

#### Backup

```
$ gpg -a --export-secret-key john.doe@example.com > secret_key
$ gpg -a --gen-revoke john.doe@example.com > revocation_cert.gpg
```

> #### Removing the Primary Key

```
$ gpg -a --export-secret-subkeys john.doe@example.com > secret_subkeys.gpg
$ gpg --delete-secret-keys john.doe@example.com
Delete this key from the keyring? (y/N) y
This is a secret key! - really delete? (y/N) y
$ gpg --import secret_subkeys.gpg
```

This leaves them in a "laptop" state with the primary secret key missing.
Transfer is done via

```
$ gpg -a --export-secret-keys john.doe@example.com > laptop_keys_secret.gpg
$ gpg -a --export john.doe@example.com > laptop_keys_public.gpg
```

(transfer via USB-Stick or CD) and on the laptop

```
$ gpg --import laptop_keys_public.gpg
$ gpg --import laptop_keys_secret.gpg
```

Comment: -1. Doesn't answer the question, promotes insecure practices among inexperienced users (copy-pasting instead of understanding the commands).

Comment: @berbt: Thanks for the feedback. You deem the steps correct, but do not like the presentation, right?

Comment: No, not really. The steps summarized here omit the vast majority of background and security information described in the blog post. As cookbooks are usually followed by beginners, who probably won't do further research (otherwise they wouldn't follow a cookbook), they'll skip the whole point of creating and storing the keys in a secure environment.

Comment: As an occasional PGP user, I very much appreciate the `cookbook` style you presented. I don't agree with @berbt, because most beginners would give up long before they figure out everything. So giving them a recipe only help them along. Surely they will look up some of the stuff shown, if they are interested enough to use PGP in the first place.

Answer (score 18):

**Key expiration** makes sense only if you can predict a point in time where the key will cease to be secure, due to advances in Science, technology, or lack of interest on your part with regards to protection of the private key. Whether a given asymmetric key will become weak in the future depends on estimates on future increase of computational power (which is only fuzzily predictable) and new scientific findings (which are not predictable at all). For computational power, various researchers and institutional bodies have published recommendations with predictive equations; see [this site](http://www.keylength.com/) for a good survey. Remember that while a good deal of Science and informed guesses have gone into these recommendations, their predictive success rate is not necessarily better than if they had slaughtered a sheep and looked at its liver to unravel the will of the gods.

Anyway, the usual assumption is that 2048-bit RSA keys should hold the line up to at least year 2030, and probably longer, under the following conditions:

- The key was properly generated with a [cryptographically secure PRNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator). (GnuPG is believed to use the OS resources properly, but so was OpenSSL until [that time when Debian goofed spectacularly](http://www.debian.org/security/2008/dsa-1571)).
- No mathematician finds a deadly shortcut to [integer factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization) (last major advance was the discovery of the [General Number Field Sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_number_field_sieve) in 1989; since then, research has focused on a lot of small, cumulative optimizations; current record is [768 bits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_numbers#RSA-768)).
- Computers keep on running under the physical laws as we know them, and, in particular, [quantum computers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_computer) keep on being theoretical only (a few QC were built, but the current record seems to be the factorization of an 8-bit integer).

While any of these conditions may fail in the future, the time of failure cannot be predicted with any kind of accuracy, so you cannot design your key expiration policy around them. The best you can do is to *suppose* that they won't occur, and pray for the best.

DSA and ElGamal keys offer similar resistance for the same key lengths; i.e. 2048 bits for these should be fine, too.

On a more practical point of view, you should keep your expiration dates [before year 2038](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).

**Your master key should be kept *mostly* offline**. If your master key is protected by a really strong pass phrase, then it can be stored *anywhere*, in particular in an online computer. But when you *type* that pass phrase, you have to be sure that the machine you are using at that time is "clean" and not riddled with keyloggers and other nefarious add-ons. The master key is "important" (at least for you), and you really do not want to see it stolen. A computer which is "online" and has been involved in daily Internet-related activities cannot be considered to be clean with 100% guarantee.

So *storage* on your computer, smartphone, Gmail account... is fine, as long as *usage* is on a dedicated offline computer. You should use your master key only to emit sub-keys, i.e. once in a decade at most. This raises the additional issue of the pass phrase: how will you remember a pass phrase that you never type, ten years from now ?

For really good resilience, I suggest **printing** the master key file (Base64-encoded), then writing the passphrase with a pencil (do *not* use your printer for that !) on the same paper, and storing that in a bank safe. At worst, if ten years from now you lost the file *and* forgot the pass phrase, you can still type it in and recover your master key.

Comment: Good point about Y2k38... But 25 years sounds like a reasonable time span for a primary key anyway. So would an OpenPGP card (possibly with a dedicated PIN pad) count as offline?

Comment: The dedicated PIN pad is a good move: it _should_ resist hostile hijacking, even if the machine is clock-full of virus and malware. However, when you use the master key, regardless of the PIN pad, you do not _see_ what is signed with the key. An OpenPGP card, like encryption with a very random password, means that the key is safe _as long as you do not type the PIN or password_. But when you do, anything goes.